# Android navigation component back Button doesn´t work

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-databinding, android-viewmodel

I have my activity:

```
<layout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<data>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="model" />
</data>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout_wallet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/appCompatImageView_go_back"
                    android:layout_width="28dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:tint="@color/colorWhite"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_ico_arrow_left" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="38dp"
                    android:tint="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:src="@drawable/tuya_logo_top"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/appCompatImageView_help"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_tuya_help"
                    android:tint="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.4" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_wallet"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/wallet_navigation"
            app:defaultNavHost="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Then i created the Nav Graph:
[image: NavGraph]

When i navigate to The first fragment, everything is fine. from that first fragment i navigate to another fragment using:

```
findNavController().navigate(WalletRegisterFragmentDirections.actionWalletRegisterFragmentToWalletRegisterConfirmFragment(
                        viewModel.getExpeditionDate(), viewModel.expeditionPlace
                    ))
```

Then, when in the second fragment, i try to go back to previous fragment using:

```
(activity as WalletActivity).appCompatImageView_go_back.setOnClickListener {
        requireActivity().onBackPressed()
    }
```

But the behaviour is not working as expected, the navigation doesn`t go back to previous fragment instead reload the current fragment, as a workaround i used:

```
requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.nameofFirstFragment)
    }
```

To navigate to previous fragment, but i dont want to use that behaviour, because doesn't save the instance of the previous fragment, intead, create a new instance.

What i'm doing wrong and why the navigation component back button doesn't work?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried looking at OnStart, OnStop, OnCreate, etc events for your fragments? What information does that give you?

Comment: @BrentGeorge When click on backButton the OnStop method is called but immediately recreates the current (second) fragment and stays there.

Comment: Are you calling navigate() in your first fragment within the `observe()` call of a `LiveData`? Please include some more context with how you move from the first fragment to the second.

Comment: @ianhanniballake yess!, i'm calling the navigate() inside an Observe(), i did reset the viewModel variable and it works.